# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lcms in java.library.path: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/lib/server

Tags: java, apache-tika, openjdk-11, pdfparser

I am using PDF parser class from apache tika parser jar which is working fine with openjdk 8 but same code is failing when i have updated the openjdk to 11. i have tried updating the tika parser version to latest but still code is failing with the error below:-

`

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lcms in java.library.path: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-11- 
  openjdk/lib/server
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2673)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
    at java.desktop/sun.java2d.cmm.lcms.LCMS$1.run(LCMS.java:209)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

`

Can someone suggest any solution to overcome it using openjdk 11 only. Thanks

Comment: This seems relevant? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4950  If that's not satisfactory, perhaps ask on the pdfbox user's list? https://pdfbox.apache.org/mailinglists.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved after updating tika-parsers-standard-package and tika-core version to 2.6.0 and PDF box version to 2.0.27.